# if file exists php

Tags: php

I use following code to delete old image from ftp...

```
unlink(getcwd() . '/images/' . $row['pic']);
```

But it throws errors in case there is not image, so i have tried using file_exists() but that didn't work too, so how can i check if there is an image before trying to delete. thanks.

```
if(file_exists(getcwd() . '/images/pics/' . $row['pic'])) 
{ 
   unlink(getcwd() . '/images/pics/' . $row['pic']);
}
```

Comment: Show the code you tried with  `file_exists`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

often hosters use different user for ftp and apache… could it be, that you don't have chmodded your images, so the www-user can't delete them?

edit:

maybe is_writable is the better solution for you:

```
if(is_writable(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/pics/' . $row['pic'])){
  unlink(dirname(__FILE__) . '/images/pics/' . $row['pic']); 
}
```

Comment: it deletes image only if there is an image, but it throws error if there is not any image, so i want to use any function to check if image exists before deleting it.

Comment: why should i use `is_writeable` instead of `getcwd()` ?

Comment: you mean dirname() instead of getcwd()? doesn't make a big difference.. but you realy should use is_writable instead of file_exists, it checks if the file exists, but it checks also if your have enough rights to modify it.

Answer (score 3):

First check what getcwd() is returning. Probably false, so that means you do not have the right permissions set. Therefore your path is not correctly constructed. Check [getcwd() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php), change permissions or contact your system administrator. Also take a snap at `dirname(__FILE__)`

Comment: it deletes image fine using getcwd if there is an image, but it throws error if image is not there.

Comment: please provide the error info. If you var_dump() the constructed path, what does it say?

Answer (score 3):

First you can store the image path in a `$path` variable. Then you may test if the image is there and it's writable, and only then, delete it.

```
$path = getcwd() . '/images/pics/';
if( file_exists( $path . $row['pic'] ) && is_writable( $path . $row['pic'] ) ){
  unlink( $path . $row['pic'] ); 
}
```

If you are using PHP 5 and want to know more about any exception that may be thrown, in the meantime you can surround the whole expression with a `try...catch` statement:

```
try{
    $path = getcwd() . '/images/pics/';
    if( file_exists( $path . $row['pic'] ) && is_writable( $path . $row['pic'] ) ){
      unlink( $path . $row['pic'] ); 
    }
} catch (Exception $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    echo $exc->getTraceAsString();
}
```

This probably won't solve the problem, but may help clarifying why it is happening.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I allowed the user to upload UP TO 8 images. But let's say they only uploaded four... Then deleted the post. I had an error for the other four images because they didn't exist. 
So this is what I did...

```
$GetImages = "SELECT * FROM sales_images WHERE ID = $imgID";

$GotImages = $conn->query($GetImages);

    while($pic = $GotImages->fetch_assoc())
{
    $path = '../images/sales/';
    $img1 = $pic['img1'];
    $img2 = $pic['img2'];
    $img3 = $pic['img3'];
    $img4 = $pic['img4'];
    $img5 = $pic['img5'];
    $img6 = $pic['img6'];
    $img7 = $pic['img7'];
    $img8 = $pic['img8'];
}


if (!empty($img1)) {
unlink($path . $img1);
}
if (!empty($img2)) {
unlink($path . $img2);
}
if (!empty($img3)) {
unlink($path . $img3);
}
if (!empty($img4)) {
unlink($path . $img4);
}
if (!empty($img5)) {
unlink($path . $img5);
}
if (!empty($img6)) {
unlink($path . $img6);
}
if (!empty($img7)) {
unlink($path . $img7);
}
if (!empty($img8)) {
unlink($path . $img8);
}
```

This worked great and threw no errors. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -4):

Try to add @ in front of unlink(getcwd() . '/images/' . $row['pic']);

@unlink(getcwd() . '/images/' . $row['pic']);

If there is a file it would be deleted, and if there is not you will not get a error message.

Comment: @usoban it's going to be the only way if this is due to a race condition. Show a better one

Comment: @usoban Can you explain why suppressing the error in this case is so VERY bad?

Comment: Because supressing errors is NEVER a solution. Maybe you'll get some other error in production, at least log it somewhere, not supress. The problem clearly is with the permissions.

Comment: I agree with usoban, you should never execute anything that you are not 100% percent sure of working. Even if it looks harmless like surpressing an unlink.